# remove spaces after comma and ' or before and after this symbol '

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have text like bellow, I need to remove spaces after comma and ' (single quote) or before and after this symbol ' (single quote)

```
$text = "'game', ' open world', ' test rpg'"
```

Expected Result

```
$text = "'game','open world','test rpg'"
```

I have tried this one bellow but remove every space

```
$tested = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $text);
```

Comment: `$text = 'game', ' open world', ' test rpg'` That doesn't look like a valid string..? Did you mean to enclose in `"`?

Comment: yes, it is inside a string, ill update it

Comment: Should the space after `open world` be removed if the text was `$text = "'game', ' open world ', ' test rpg'";`

Comment: you can `trim` when ever you want to use certain item.
.else, what is the purpose, explain where you want to use this string next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/\s+?\'\s+?/', '\'', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$text = "'game', ' open world', ' test rpg'";
$str = explode(",",$text);
$arr = array();
foreach ($str as $key) {
    array_push($arr, trim($key));
}

print_r(implode(',',$arr));
?>
```

Check out these php functions [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
$text  = explode("', ' ",$text);
$text = implode("','",$text);
```

Option 2:

```
$text = str_replace("', ' ","','",$text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern should work.

[Regexr](https://regexr.com/3s6pn)

**Code:**

```
$text = "'game', ' open world', ' test rpg'";

echo preg_replace('/(\s?\'\s?)/', "'", $text);
```

Comment: your answer has space after comma

Answer (score 0):

Simple and fast solution just use of php `explode` and `implode` function

```
echo $text = "'game', ' open world', ' test rpg'";
print_r(implode(',',explode(',', $text)));
```

Comment: it should be in string mate, if i did it will inside array

Answer (score 0):

The previous regex answers do not account for spaces that come after a comma (and aren't before a `'`), such as `open, world`. Here's a solution that works for commas followed by a space as well:

```
$text = "'game', ' open, world', ' test ' rpg'";
echo preg_replace("/(?: *(?='))([',]) */", '$1', $text);
```